# User-friendly Haskell IDE with console input integration

Tags: ide, haskell

Is there an alternative to the sleek Leksah Haskell IDE? It seems like there are not many user-friendly Haskell IDEs out there, and Leksah, although it is amazing in terms of GUI presentability, lacks console input integration.

Basically I am looking for a user-friendly IDE for coding in Haskell, not as an extension or plugin to another IDE but as a standalone development environment like Visual Studio is to C#.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What features do you want? Questions must be understandable on their own. Assume that nobody knows Leksah, and describe exactly what you need, then reopen the question, thanks! :-)

Comment: Edited and clarified :)

Comment: Most IDEs are capable of handling several languages, including Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm asking about Haskell though, basically a glorified Haskell compiler extension, like Leksah, but not Leksah.